# Fragment Back Stack onSaveInstanceState Behavior

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I'm playing around with the fragment back stack and I noticed some odd behavior. I wrote a simple test program consisting of a single activity with a fragment container. I have a two buttons, one which replaces the current fragment with a new instance of Fragment A, and one which replaces the current fragment with a new instance of Fragment B.

```
// On Button A click:
FragmentA fragment = FragmentA.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentA).addToBackStack(null).commit();


// On Button B click:
FragmentB fragment = FragmentB.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentB).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I'm logging each time a fragment calls onSaveInstanceState.

When I add 10 instances of FragmentA in a row, then perform a stop of the activity, I only get 2 onSaveInstanceState calls.

When I alternate between adding FragmentA, FragmentB, FragmentA, FragmentB, etc..., I get the same amount of onSaveInstanceState calls as there are fragments on the back stack.

Now here's the kicker. If I add 10 instances of FragmentA in a row, but set a field (for example, a simple int field) on *every other* one, then I get 10 onSaveInstanceState calls.

In contrast, if there are 10 instances of FragmentA on the back stack, each with the same exact field values, then I only get 2 onSaveInstanceState calls.

What's going on here? Is Android doing something special where it is noticing multiple fragments of the same type and same field values on the back stack, and hence only calling onSaveInstanceState on some of them?

Comment: If no one has an answer for you, I can make a suggestion: whenever I ask myself what the Android system is doing, I leverage the fact that Android is open source and completely browsable in Android Studio. Fire up Android studio, start stepping through the methods, and follow the bread crumbs until you get your answer.